# Detect an edited csv file using PHPExcel

Tags: php, csv, phpexcel

I am using PHPExcel to validate csv files before parsing them and storing in my database and server. I am trying to use the file properties to determine if the file has been modified or if it is the original file. I have used the following for .xls, .xlsx with great results (using the appropriate reader);

```
    $file = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
    $reader = new PHPExcel_Reader_CSV();
    if($reader->canRead($file)){
        $object = $reader->load($file);
        $created = $object->getProperties()->getCreated();
        $modified = $object->getProperties()->getModified();
        if(!$created===$modified){
             //File has been edited and cannot be used
        }else{
            //File is good, continue processing
        }
    }
```

However, when using CSV files, NOTHING is working as expected. I renamed an MS-Word doc to .csv->passed, edited a csv->passed, even used a .jpg->passed. What on earth am I missing?? Any help would greatly appreciated! Edit->I should note that `$created` and `$modifed` are an exact match when `var_dump($object)` despite having edited the file and confirming the changes within the document properties.

Comment: I think you made a typo in your if statement. Try to replace it with ```$created !== $modified```

Comment: The format is correct when calling the methods using other file types (denotes exact match of variables). When var_dump($object) is called, the 'created' and 'modified' values are in fact an exact match. I should have specified that in my original post. However, they shouldn't be as I am changing the file before testing. The file properties when obsrved in Windows, correctly show the different dates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The properties values accessible from PHPExcel are those stored within the file itself, not within the directory entries for that file.

CSV files don't have any inherent properties of their own; CSV is purely a raw data file format These property methods are for accessing the properties that do exist in other spreadsheet formats such as BIFF (xls) and OfficeOpenXML (xlsx) which do support them. Loading a CSV (or other format that doesn't support properties) into PHPExcel will provide default value for those properties (so that calls like you're making won't trigger fatal errors), but it cannot provide actual values for something that doesn't natively exist in the format being loaded.

Comment: this would explain a lot my struggle. Then the next question would be, are there any methods or libraries (JS, PHP, JQuery, JSON??) for detecting an edited CSV?

Comment: native PHP functions like [filemtime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filemtime.php) and [filectime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filectime.php) should help for files that exist on your server, because they read the timestamps from the folder information.... but if it's an uploaded file, then you need to detect the times on the client side, so PHP isn't much help, you need something js

Comment: I've accepted your answer Mark. While PHPExcel does a great job at getting the needed data from xls, xlsx etc, that data does not exist in CSV. As for the solution to my problem specifically->write a Java program that will extract the data from the source, encrypt it and then submit the file to my web application. This way I can ensure that the user has not had an opportunity to manipulate the data. With regards to your last comment and the usage of JS-> the same problem is present.Thus, the Java solution. And so begins my trudge down the road of Happy Destiny...